# Getting StackTrace/StackFrame for Controller Action in Action Filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

In an `ActionFilter` is it possible to get the current `StackFrame` for the controller's action?

When I do this,

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

`stackTrace` does not have the action.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that stack frame will have been lost as the call to action filter OnActionExecuting method is made after the action method has completed (and hence stack frame discarded).

You can programatically determine which action method was called using the filterContext though, if this was your intention.

Comment: I know I can, I just really need a `StackFrame`.

Comment: In which case you'll need to call your stack trace examining method from within your action method. If this is a generic concern you may find an AOP tool such as  PostSharp useful.